# Modified entites are not reflecting in database

Tags: jhipster

I have created a Entity for jhipster Microservice Gateway project.

Tried to modify the entity by adding new fields later. Its corresponding Java classes and Angular files got updated. But, the new field is not added in the database table.

Did i miss any other configurations ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the database changes are done by [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), i.e. you need to have a look under

`src/main/resources/config/liquibase/`

for `master.xml.` JHipster is adding all the scripts that need to be run when you start your app in `master.xml`.

When you add new fields over comand line, then the generator is modifing your  `master.xml` by adding a new change or is just updating an existing change. All the changes are located under in the folder changelog which is on the same level as `master.xml.`

Comment: As you said, the new field which was added, seen under changelog as well as in master.xml. But the new field is not reflecting in my mysql DB table.

Comment: new field in master.xml:                                                                    
<include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170420082032_added_entity_Customerdetailmaster.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

Comment: Lquibase migrations are supposed to be immutable, this is why they have checksums, rather than lidifyng an existing you should create a new one and liquibase:diff can help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. I failed to add hibernate statement under jpa in application.dev.yml.

I have added " hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update" under jpa in application.dev.yml file. And the field got inserted into mysql DB table.

Comment: This is not the right way as it is conflicting with Liquibase.

Comment: Could you please tell me the right way then ? ! If i dint add the above hibernate statement, values are not being added into the database and also getting internal server error ! Please help me on this

Comment: Read my comment on the other answer